# How can I rig separate parts of an object to move but keep it as one object?

Tags: modeling, animation, objects, bones, parent

I am a beginner in 3D modelling and wanted to create a mod for the game "City Bus manager". I know the basics of Blender but I ran into a problem.

**I need to model an animated double swing doors but as one object.**

Building the swing doors as two separate objects is not an option since the game deletes one of them no matter what. It has to be one single entity to work.

Another modder gave me the instructions to do so but I failed to make the doors move separately.

> "Create two objects, parent them, join and then split them. It creates a hole, it is still one object, but as it is split all the way, each bones can manipulate it's own part while it stay as one object."

Comment: Join the 2 parts in one object, and parent each part to its own bone?

Comment: I tried this but it didn't worked. When the two objects joins, they don't split and move as one.

Comment: You need to correctly parent the meshes to the bones, see my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294015/animating-with-bend/294020?noredirect=1#comment506485_294020

Comment: i managed to animate half of the door to one bone but  the other half and the second bone remain disconnected and move separatly from each other.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=R9rJPBWr" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/R9rJPBWr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the armature called *Left door*, shift select the armature called *Right door*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. Select the cube object, shift select the armature, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *(Parent) > With Empty Groups*. In *Edit* mode, select the cube that is supposed to be controlled by *Bone.001*, click on the *Assign* button, it should work, create a parent bone if necessary:

[image]