# Animating with bend

Tags: animation, modifiers, bones, keyframes

I am almost completely a noob with Blender, but I'm enthusiasming to it gradually for many motivations, so I decided to enter further on it and using it from now on.

I have to animate a toy denture (3 parts: jaw, mandibule and spring keys placed on the side of the mandible) for a game. The animation is:

- anticipation (the item as a whole bends towards a little, say, 45°, whilst the keys coil)
- jump (the item "springs" up for, say, 10 cm, whilst opening gape and the keys ufold)
- landing (the item closes the gape whilst landing)

Obviously the animation is on place (the coder will move it accordingly to the span required). Any suggestions? Thanks.

PS: should I bone it (2, or 3, bones?) or separate the 3 parts?

[image]

Comment: There are several ways to do it, for example you can join the 3 parts in one object, create an armature with one bone per part, parent the object to the armature With Empty Groups, then assign each part to the correct vertex group in the Object Data panel > Vertex Groups

Comment: Well, I come from being a modeler not an animator and in a different app, so most of what you say is new for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can join all your 3 objects into one object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), create an armature, activate its *In Front* option in the *Object panel > Viewport Display*, create one bone per part, plus a parent bone (a root bone), call them (<kbd>F2</kbd>) by the correct name (like *jaw_up, jaw_down*, *key* and *root*), in *Object* mode select the object, shift select the armature and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Parent With Empty Groups*:

[image]

Parenting this way will create 3 vertex groups in your objects that will have the same names as the bone, but no vertex has been assigned to any of these groups, you need to do it manually: Switch your object to *Edit* mode, select the top jaw, open the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups*, select the vertex group called *jaw_top*, click on *Assign*:

[image]

Back to *Object* mode, select the armature, switch to *Pose* mode, rotate and move the bones, keyframe, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I imported the object as a whole obj model from the app where I modeled it (sorry, but I still model in another app, 'cause Blender is still hostile to me as for modeling, but on the contrary it looks easier than the other app in animating, which sucks at it...). Sshould I import as multiple parts/layers, then rig each part, animate then ctl+j and export as fbx for the engine?

Comment: p.s. the bones actually may be 4, 'cause the keys are two, one per side.

Comment: You need to join all the objects (Ctrl J) then rig, then export

Comment: ok, then i have to import a mesh made of separate parts

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, If they are already part of the same object it's ok

Comment: Perhaps it is better if I start animating a simpler obect, such as the hammer (another character), which is a unique mesh and doesn't have movable parts...

Comment: I'm completyely lost. This happens when one passes to another app from the one in which he modeled for decades...

Comment: please share your blend file so that we understand the situation. Again if your jaws is made of several object (upper and lower jaws, keys), join them in one object (this is my proposition but you can rig with another method with separate objects)

Comment: I cannot grant the rights, as it is something for a commercial project.

Comment: Here it is the file https://file.io/6AC8FQkTKDJH

Comment: So everything seems ok, you've joined the objects into one object, now you just need to follow the steps I described, no?

Comment: I'm unable to. Sorry. I think I drop this and I try to have somebody join whatever. I'm definitely not tayolored for animation.

Comment: Any rig should ideally have a root bone, especially if you export them, some softwares require it and it's pretty much expected to have it to wear any ẅeights not used by other bones and for placement

Comment: Yes that's also what I thought afterwards, I'm going to edit

Comment: Sorry, it is completely hostile to me and I feel upset. I give up. Thank you for your time.

Comment: maybe you are going too fast and you should follow some tutorials on the basics   ;)

Comment: Hi Moon. Yes it was so! But I've heard that Blender was magically easy at animating, so I tryied it first off with some basic knowledge of animation from other apps. Anyway, perhaps I succeeded, albeit I don't know if the process is good when the animation will be exported in Unity. I imported it multi-part, rigged/binded each piece, then animated the whole (I succeeded also with appying bend, with a null!). Will it work in Unity?